# pod structure for ember component not working - embercli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

`using ember-cli: 0.1.9`

First I tried creating a simple component with `ember g component my-component`.

It created the following files

```
installing
  create app/components/my-component.js
  create app/templates/components/my-component.hbs
installing
  create tests/unit/components/my-component-test.js
```

This worked fine I could then use `{{ my-component }}` from my templates.

But then I tried to create the same component in pod structure with the `--pod` flag it doesn't work. Calling this component while in POD structure does not seem to do anything when I try to call this component.

`ember g component my-componenttwo --pod`

```
installing
  create app/pods\components\my-componenttwo/component.js
  create app/pods\components\my-componenttwo/template.hbs
installing
  create tests/unit/pods\components\my-componenttwo/component-test.js
```

I configured in `app/config/environment.js` the following `podModulePrefix: 'app/pods',`

Comment: did you use pods other than for components? do pods work otherwise? I'm currently not having _any_ of my pods show up. Trying to figure out if it's an npm package that's throwing it off. Coffeescript, maybe.

Comment: yes the pods worked other than for components. Pods also worked but can't make it work for components

Answer (score 0):

I (and many others, it appears) had a similar issue. `podModulePrefix` needs to be set to `<modulePrefix>/pods` to find the pods directory correctly. I doubt your modulePrefix is `app`, right, so

```
podModulePrefix: 'app/pods'
```

looks incorrect.

environment.js should look something like:

```
var ENV = {
  modulePrefix: 'project',
  podModulePrefix: 'project/pods
  // ...
}
```